# Определить где вызвана SASS функция

Tags: css, sass, scss

Есть sass функция, возможно ли внутри нее проверить где она вызвана/во что обернута?

```
@function fun($value) {
  @if (??? tablet) {
    $value: 1;
  }
  @return $value;
}
```

В данном случае вместо 42 подсунуть 1 по условию.

```
.block {
  width: fun(72);
  @include tablet {
    width: fun(42);
  }
}
```

Чтобы получилось:

```
.block {
    width: 72;
}
@media tablet {
    .block {
        width: 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: а почему просто 1 не передать при вызове? `@include tablet {
    width: fun(1);
  }`

Comment: Пример упрощенный, передавать нужно каждый раз разные значения а по условию менять обработку данных

Comment: Все равно непонятно, что мешается передавать нужные значения в месте вызова функции?

Comment: помимо передачи значения нужно обработать их внутри функции в зависимости от нахождения в обертке tablet. То есть, раньше приходилось передавать два значения, условно foo(42, tablet), теперь стало интересно можно ли средствами sass все это сократить

Comment: Судя по всему так нельзя